# Naming of subchapters which deal with same topic in different case

Tags: titles

Is there any naming convention or strategy for subchapters, if they are about the same phenomenon but observed within a different case?

Let's say my structure looks as follows:

```
4.1 Usage of Software-as-a-Service
4.1.1 Usage of Software-as-a-Service at Company A
4.1.2 Usage of Software-as-a-Service at Company B
```

How should one select the titles for a thesis?

Answer (score 6):

> How should one select the titles for a thesis?

It is rather repetitive to use structures such as

```
 4.1 Usage of Software-as-a-Service
 4.1.1 Usage of Software-as-a-Service at Company A
 4.1.2 Usage of Software-as-a-Service at Company B
```

I suggest something less repetitive, e.g.,

```
 4.1 Software-as-a-Service
 4.1.1 Case study: Company A
 4.1.2 Case study: Company B
```